# how to reference runtime code with dsl grammar element in xtext

Tags: xtext

I am working in xtext dsl but getting errors. I have dsl from existing ecore model.

[image]

Please see the image and guide me about the error. I shall be thankful.

This is my model

[image]

Comment: does SchemaState have an attribute named "name". if not you need to implement IQualifiedNameProvider (usually DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider subclass)

Comment: can you also show where in your model the schemastate instance is defined?

Comment: @IQualifiedNameProvider (usually DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider subclass) .......... Where to write this code? Actually I am exploring xtext...............Please see model image, I have attached in edit.

Comment: create in in the mydsl project. bind it in mydslruntime module

Comment: p.s: did you do the tutorials

Comment: Please guide me about tutorials.

Comment: i mean the tutorials in the xtext docs. from your post it is unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: i have an ecore mode and i want t create xtext grammar from existing ecore. Now it is giving error while writing in run time (as show in image). I think I need to update the generated grammar.

Comment: i still dont see where your schemastate is defined. you write `schemastate SchemaState`. this is the same as writing `extends SomeClass` in java. there you need to have a `public class SomeClass` somewhere. so where is your `define schemastate SchemaState` somewhere. your picture also does not seem to show the root. how would the instances look like if you would have model as .xmi instead of .mydsl

Comment: This is all auto generated (schemastate). I have shared. Please see it here: https://github.com/MisbahAwan/xtext

Comment: did you select ZNotationModel as root?

Comment: but in your ecore i dont see a containment refernce that contains a schemastate. so where shall it be defined?

Comment: e.g. `<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="ZNotationModel"><eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="schemastate" upperBound="-1" eType="#//SchemaState" containment="true"/>`

Comment: also your `<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="SchemaState">` does not have a name so you cannot reference it and would need to adopt IQualifiedNameProvider

Comment: @did you select ZNotationModel as root?..... Yes

Comment: see my other comments. your metamodel has more flaws that dont work with default conventions from Xtext.

Comment: @but in your ecore i dont see a containment refernce that contains a schemastate. so where shall it be defined? ............................. There is reference between "Schema" and "SchemaState" as "[0..1]schemastate".